# How to fix this crack in drywall?

Tags: drywall, walls, patching-drywall, spackling-paste, drywall-mud

The picture shows the crack over a door. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the extra load/movement in that area. What's the best way to fix this crack that will prevent this from re-occurring in the future?

[image]

Comment: The *best* way requires resolving whatever framing issue caused the crack. Is that what you're asking about? Otherwise, you might want to install an expansion/control channel in the drywall and re-tape to that.

Comment: Looks like an outside wall. Have you ruled out water damage? I would  use a pin type moisture meter to check.(https://www.amazon.com/General-Tools-MMD4E-Moisture-Digital/dp/B00275F5O2/)

Comment: Is this a new or newer home? If it is the crack may have been caused by settling and covering the crack may last. If it is older its time to be inspecting the foundation and structure.

Answer (score 1):

Put an expansion joint in the same location as the crack or remove the drywall and replace it but change the layout so there isn't a seam there. It's common to get cracks at doors like this, so when drywalling the professionals try not to put seams that close to either end of a door for that reason.

You can retape this as is with paper or mesh tape and joint compound, but the crack always comes back. If you go this route, trying not to slam this door will help the repair last longer.