# Is this crack something to be concerned about?

Tags: repair, crack, patching-drywall

I noticed a small crack above window frame. The window is at the top of stairwell and I’ve provided a wide shot so you can see location. The crack is small but I just wanted to get an opinion on if this is something serious. Also, should I just use tape and mud to repair or since it’s minimal just use some mud?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Of this? [Do drywall cracks pose any risk for further damage?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/196987/do-drywall-cracks-pose-any-risk-for-further-damage)

Comment: Or this? [Home Improvement
Just bought house with hairline diagonal crack from window](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/152772/just-bought-house-with-hairline-diagonal-crack-from-window)

Comment: Or this? [How to fix this crack in drywall?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/134609/how-to-fix-this-crack-in-drywall)

Comment: @isherwood the links are helpful. The house is only 5 years old so I assume it’s  due to settling but just wanted an opinion on if this was something to be concerned about.

Comment: It's fairly common for settling to occur at that point because there's a stack of framing components there that aren't always fit precisely. The answers on the questions above should cover it.