# Crack under window on the interior

Tags: drywall, windows, cracks

There is step crack under the window of my house. This is on the drywall.

Is this an issue? How do I proceed?

[image]

Comment: Or this? [Just bought house with hairline diagonal crack from window](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/152772/just-bought-house-with-hairline-diagonal-crack-from-window?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Or this? [Do drywall cracks pose any risk for further damage?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/196987/do-drywall-cracks-pose-any-risk-for-further-damage)

Comment: Or this? [How to fix this crack in drywall?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/134609/how-to-fix-this-crack-in-drywall)

Comment: Obviously a search is a good first step. If you do then post a question, be sure to provide some context. This super closeup doesn't give us any insight into the situation _around_ the crack, which is where the source of the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

Horizontal or vertical cracks in drywall are usually just cosmetic. Diagonal cracks can indicate settling.

Answer (score 0):

If you nave a basement, go check for any signs of settling. Regardless, the repair is easy. Thin layers of joint compound, sand, paint.

Comment: The repair is "easy" assuming that it's only bad drywalling. If there's a foundation, the repair isn't "easy" or "cheap"