# Crack in drywall covering window sills (Above the window, straight vertical line)

Tags: drywall, crack

The walls of this house are made with thermoblock,  it's hollow block made of polystyrene like material that gets filled in with concrete. So the inner wall from the centre is as concrete -> polystyrene -> drywall -> plaster+mesh -> paint...
The sills were poured on the spot on top of the window openings.

Are these cracks in the drywall a sign of something serious? I do not see similar cracks outside, for the same sill. The outside is concrete -> polystyrene -> plaster with mesh -> decorative stucco.

What would be the best way to hide these cracks?
[image: crack in drywall]

Comment: Or this? [Just bought house with hairline diagonal crack from window](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/152772/just-bought-house-with-hairline-diagonal-crack-from-window?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Or this? [Do drywall cracks pose any risk for further damage?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/196987/do-drywall-cracks-pose-any-risk-for-further-damage)

Comment: Or this? [How to fix this crack in drywall?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/134609/how-to-fix-this-crack-in-drywall)

Comment: [Many more related questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Adiy.stackexchange.com+drywall+crack+window&rlz=1C1GCEU_enUS1019US1019)

Comment: @isherwood https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/134609/how-to-fix-this-crack-in-drywall is the only similar one it seems. Others are at different areas of different angles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the typical spot where cracks show when a house is settling. They are caused by the shearing force of the square wall now converting into a parallelogram.

All houses settle, so if your house is new and the cracks do not widen or continue to appear around door and window frames, all is good. Just repair the cracks with typical drywall repair techniques, eg taping/mesh, drywall compound, feather, sand, prime, paint.